# Starting virtual cam automatically by modifying the obs64.exe file in the source folder

Tags: windows-10, obs-studio

I'm starting OBS automatically by using the software System Scheduler; this software requires as input the obs64.exe file in the source folder, not a shortcut of OBS.

I know that, by typing --startvirtualcam after the last double quotes in the target box inside the properties of the OBS shortcut, I can run automatically the virtual cam, but it seems that this is not possible if I use the obs64.exe file in the source folder.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Is using "System Scheduler" a requirement? You could definitely do this from Task Scheduler (built-in to Windows).

Comment: Hello @Romen I tried the Task Scheduler in Windows; I watched tutorials on how to use it, and on my PC it never worked. Maybe there is a way to start the virtual cam automatically directly inside OBS without the --startvirtualcam command in the shortcut file.

Comment: You could create a batch file and use this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler

Comment: Hello @Gantendo thank you for your suggestion; I prefer to avoid the Windows' tools, is there another way.

Comment: Yes, make a batch file and start it with the System Scheduler. Or just start it with the System Scheduler but specify that it must use the --startvirtualcam parameter

Comment: https://www.fileeagle.com/data/2016/03/Screenshot_0_System-Scheduler-FREE-536x421.jpg There is a Parameters box. Put `--startvirtualcam` in there. According to https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/wiki/launch-parameters you must set a working directory (called Working Dir in System Scheduler)

Comment: Hello @Gantendo could you tell me where I should creare the working directory please? I didn't get what is the partially hidden window. In this case the batch file is necessary?

Comment: I updated my comment above (found a better screenshot). The working directory is the folder where `obs64.exe` is located (in other words, where you installed OBS). It is probably C:\Program Files\OBS\

Comment: Thank you a lot for your precious help @Gantendo

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is solved.